# Не получается добавить динамично LinearLayout на ViewPager в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, placeholder

Решил создать первый проект на андроид и возникли трудности (не судите строго)).
Проблема заключается в том, что после отрисовки **Activity** где в ней уже находится **ScrollView**, а в ней **LinearLayout** (через *XML*). В коде поэтапно добавляются динамически другие **View** (**TextView**, **Button**, **ImageView** и т.д.) через метод *displayAllInfo()*.
В конце я добавляю **LinearLayout** в **ArrayList**.
После этого хочу из листа добавлять во вьюпейджер лаяуты, но тщетно...
Вот как это выглядит:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.info_unit);

        linearLayout3 = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout3);
        displayAllInfo();

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fabPlus);
        fab.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String id = info.getID().toLowerCase();
            tabName = MainActivity.translatorJson.Attempt(id);

            MainActivity.tabNameList.add(tabName);
            MainActivity.tabContentList.add(linearLayout3);
        });
    }
```

Через **PageViewModel** пытаюсь взять значения из **ArrayList**:

```
public class PageViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<Integer> mIndex = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private LiveData<LinearLayout> linearlayout = Transformations.map(mIndex, new Function<Integer, LinearLayout>() {
        @Override
        public LinearLayout apply(Integer input) {
            return MainActivity.tabContentList.get(input - 1);
        }
    });

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        mIndex.setValue(index);
    }
    public LiveData<LinearLayout> getLL() { 
        return linearlayout; 
    }
}
```

И в конечном счете присваиваю это все дело через **PlaceHolderFragment**:

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    private PageViewModel pageViewModel;

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int index) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, index);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PageViewModel.class);
        int index = 1;
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            index = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        }
        pageViewModel.setIndex(index);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_compare, container, false);
        pageViewModel.getLL().observe(this, new Observer<LinearLayout>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(LinearLayout linearLayout) {
                LinearLayout ll = root.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout4);
                ll.removeAllViews();
                //ll = linearLayout;
                ll.addView(linearLayout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

**linearLayout4** это пустая вьюха для отрисовки полученной **linearLayout**.
Для **PageView** отдельная активность (*activity_compare*, а в ней лежит *fragment_compare*). Была создана через шаблон Android Studio **Tabbed Activity**. И при ее открытии выскакивет ошибка.
Вот последние строки дебагера:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5106)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4892)
        at com.sashantgroup.fafwiki.ui.main.PlaceholderFragment$2.onChanged(PlaceholderFragment.java:67)
        at com.sashantgroup.fafwiki.ui.main.PlaceholderFragment$2.onChanged(PlaceholderFragment.java:61)
```

Прошу помощи (уже месяц не могу победить проблему), заранее спасибо!)

Comment: Вы делаете очень неправильные вещи. Использовать статические переменные и вьюхи в LiveData и ViewModel  - крайне неправильно. У вас, видимо, очень много запутанного кода уже написано, весь он явно не попал в вопрос, так что можно лишь самые общие советы дать по переписыванию почти всего вашего кода: убрать статические переменные, и вместо вьюх передавать в/из ViewModel  данные, а не вьюхи. И создавать вьюхи на основе данных там, где это нужно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо за разъяснение) Буду переписывать в соответствии с вашими замечаниями. В C# такое прокатывало, а здесь, к моему сожалению, нет(

Comment: Тут, возможно, тоже прокатит, если исправить ту ошибку, что у вас в логах. Её можно исправить, если перед добавлением вьюхи проверять нет ли у неё уже родителя и, если есть - удалить вьюху из родителя перед её добавлением в нового родителя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, решил проблему вынесением того что находилось в активити в отдельный класс, и данные передавал как экземпляр класса со свойствами через геттеры и сеттеры. Собственно этот класс и пропихивал в лист вместо linearLayout3.
**@ЮрийСПб** спасибо то что направили в верное русло :)